# XmlPullParser or JSoup for parsing HTML in Android

Tags: android, parsing

I have a string containing html code and I want to extract only certain elements from it.

I've been looking around google and stack overflow for a while, and it seems like most suggested solutions are to use Android XmlPullParser or JSoup.

Which one of these methods is best to parse hmtl in android and why?

Comment: Post your code or Strings!

Comment: @GiovanniTerlingen What does it matter what my string is? It's a string with the html source code of a webpage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSOUP will be the obvious choice as you can easily identify the HTML elements, and create objects from them . Finally you can do your required operations, convert the document in string and finally set in your view.

Below is a code snippet where I needed to remove the header and footer of my webpage and then show it in my view.

```
if(document!=null) {

               if (document.getElementById("header").getElementById("site-head") != null) {
                   document.getElementById("header").getElementById("site-head").remove();
                }
                if (document.getElementById("footer") != null) {
                    document.getElementById("footer").remove();
                } if (document.getElementsByClass("fs-footer-newsletter") != null) {
                    document.getElementsByClass("fs-footer-newsletter").remove();
                }
                String modifiedDocument = document.toString();
                modifiedDocument = modifiedDocument.replace("<html lang=\"en-US\" prefix=\"og: http://ogp.me/ns#\" class=\"no-js\">","<html lang=\"en-US\" prefix=\"og: http://ogp.me/ns#\" class=\"no-js\" style=\"margin-top:0 !important;\">");
                modifiedDocument = modifiedDocument.replace("<header id=\"header\">","<header id=\"header\" style=\"margin-top:-16px;\">");
                modifiedDocument = modifiedDocument.replace("<ul class=\"main-filters\">","<ul class=\"main-filters\" style=\"top:0;\">");
                Document d = Jsoup.parse(modifiedDocument);
                WebSettings ws = getItemWebview.getSettings();
                ws.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
                Log.i("modifiedDocument",document.toString());
                if(isURLForShop) {
                    loadingImg.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    getItemWebview.loadDataWithBaseURL(storeUrl, d.toString(), "text/html", "utf-8", "");
                }else{
                    loadingImg.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    getItemWebview.loadDataWithBaseURL(restyleDenimURL, d.toString(), "text/html", "utf-8", "");
                }
            }
```

Comment: Thanks. I've also found that I can directly get the html code from an URL using JSoup, so it simplifies a lot the way I was getting the html string :D

Comment: Done :p I couldn't do it before cause of the timelimit

Comment: Hi @Tirafesi, how to do it? Can you please describe me if you did it?